# Using enums to perform commands

Tags: java, command-line, enums, functor

thanks for reading,

I want to implement an enum, that give a list of valid commands. I ask the user for a command and some arguments that go with it (and it would be lovely if that could be internationalized) parse that list, check if it was a valid command, and then run the correct command with the arguments, or report an error. How can I make it call a function and pass arguments to it?

This looks like something of a skeleton, but from what I understand, execute() has to be parameterless.

```
public enum CommandWords {
      OPEN() {
           public void execute() { 
                System.out.println("Now opening"); 
           }
      },
      SAVE() {
           public void execute() { 
                System.out.println("save a file"); 
           }
      };
      //And more methods, that actually manipulate the file

      //template method
      public abstract void execute();
 }
```

Sorry, there was one thing I wasn't clear about. The method that I want to execute, isn't held here in this class, it's defined somewhere else. I need to pass arguments to that method. I'm confused because in reality, I don't want to override the method, I want to hold a reference to another method.

Comment: What's wrong? You can call `execute()` like `CommandWords.OPEN.execute()`. In your example your abstract method returns `boolean` and you override it with `void`. Also, I think you don't need the `@Override` in this case.

Comment: Instead of enums, I would suggest taking a look at the [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). I think it's probably a bit more flexible than a single enum.

Comment: execute() can have parameters.

Comment: For instance `Object execute(Object... args)`